# Is there a way to default ActiveRecord query by attribute to "any"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `available` attribute on a `Product` model which is a boolean.

I'm defining a helper method that takes an argument, for example:

```
def family_products(available: true)
 Product.where(available: available)
end
```

This is fine for `true` or `false` -- but what I would like is a default of `all`.

Is it possible without creating a conditional wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
def family_products(available: [true, false])
  Product.where(available: [available])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would define a `scope` in your `Product` model like this.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
scope :all_family_products, -> { where('available = ? or available = ?', true, false) }
end
```

Now calling `Product.all_family_products` returns both ***available products(available = true)*** and ***unavailable products(available = false)***